# How to move messages from Postbox local to IMAP

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I'm trying to move 13000 messages from a local Postbox mail folder (Postbox is a version of thunderbird) to IMAP.

If I try and move the messages, then about 600 messages get copied, and then the process stops. Is there a way (other than choosing 600 messages at a time and moving them) that I can move these messages.

e.g. Are there any utilities that'll take a thunderbird mail folder and individually move them to an IMAP folder? Is this a known problem?

*update:* I've moved the Mailbox file to thunderbird, and I'm trying to move it from there. I'm getting error messages now about invalid headers, but it seems to work better. Unless someone says different, I'm putting this down to bugs in Postbox.

Comment: Aha, invalid headers, that's a hot topic too: http://superuser.com/questions/42009

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create some message rule, which applies to all messages, and then run that rule on your local folders? That will basically move the messages one-by-one, so should not hit some limit of 600 messages.

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, *it doesn't seem to work* might need some more info...?

Comment: Clicking the Apply Rule button flickers between "Stop" and "Apply Rule". It runs through for a while, and then stops. Messages are copied to the IMAP folder, but not deleted on the Local Folder.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start looking for help is [IMAP Tools](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/). I think Thunderbird stores messages in the mbox format so their MboxToIMAP.pl script may work best. There is also a MozillaToImap.pl script which may be better.